# Visual Studio no longer generates Constructor/Deconstructor when creating class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, default-constructor

so before whenever I created a class in VS19, it would do the following.

```
//.h
#pragma once
class Game {
     Game();
     ~Game();
};

//.cpp
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game() {
}

Game::~Game() {
}
```

However, now it does the following

```
//.h
#pragma once
class Game {

};

//.cpp
#include "Game.h"
```

And this may be a stupid thing and you may ask "Are you really that lazy to write that code?" And the answer is well, yeah. I liked it when VS19 created it automatically because it was another thing I would not have to worry about making. I could just quickly start the class. So I'm asking, is there somewhere in the VS19 options bar that activates this again?

Comment: I don't know whether this changed as default behavior in VS, however the second variant is a safer default than the first one. Declaring user-defined constructors and/or a destructor as in the example incurs many changes from the default behavior of classes and you probably don't want to have that in most classes. It makes the class non-trivial, non-aggregate, non-literal and will inhibit the implicit declaration of move constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @uneven_mark Yes, those were typos and VS never added private/public before.

Comment: Then this would be rather pointless. Inside a class definition introduced by the `class` keyword, by default everything is `private`, meaning that it would cause you to be unable to properly created instances of this class at all (as the constructor and destructor are inaccessible).

Comment: I would be concerned that I was missing an opportunity for abstraction, or a need for code generation, if I were writing enough classes for this to make any difference whatsoever.  (And don’t use `#pragma once`, or `.h` as a C++ header file name.)

Comment: This change is the default behavior and there is no such setting in vs2019. You can create a class, write the constructor and destructor, and then export it as a template, then you can use this template in add new item. [How to: Create item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019#add-an-item-template-to-the-add-new-item-dialog-box)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT: That would seem to be an answer.

Comment: @DavisHerring yes i know about the `#pragma once` and i do use `#ifndef ...` or the `.h` those are just written code i made on the spot.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-code-snippets?view=vs-2022#class-vs-classi

Answer (score 3):

This change is the default behavior and there is no such setting in vs2019. You can create a class, write the constructor and destructor, and then export it as a template, then you can use this template in add new item. [How to: Create item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019#add-an-item-template-to-the-add-new-item-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0):

@Legat

> this may be a stupid thing

No, it's not stupid.

Visual Studio 2019 (and 2022) **will** create constructors and deconstructors automatically when you enter "class" and then accept the "class" code suggestion that is offered before you continue typing.

result...

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

private:

};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```